# Manufacturing of Bio Molecules

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

Can we Manufacture bio molecules say e.g. the simplest Sugar, C12,H22,O11 the way we do with any other mechanical component. So, we know all about the Structure and arrangement of Atoms in Sugar - so do the design send the commands to the manufacturing machine which will use C,H and O elements and put them in them specified order !

If it's not doable today, what's the reason? - 
1. Our lack of understanding of the Structure of Sugar atoms  or
2. The specialized method which will put nascent atoms into the configuration of Sugar. Are people anywhere in the world trying to work this way? Please give references.

Comment: If that is meant to be sucrose, that isn't the simplest sugar. Technically I think it would be glyceraldehyde (C3) which makes the task a little easier. If you want a cyclic molecule maybe ribose, C5.

Comment: This is more about chemistry than biology (synthetic chemistry to be exact) and should be moved to Chem.SE in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with Armatus on that one, I'm afraid. You'll have better luck on the chemistry site.

Comment: this question needs more detail - its not going to make more sense to chemists. what is it we don't know about molecules like sugars?

Comment: Dear Shigeta, my question simply means that, do we know enough to create molecules like Sugar from scratch. I am not talking about synthesizing. Or is it that we know all the details, but it is not possible because of technological limitations (it may or may not be practical, I am not bothered). I am talking about possibilities and am keen to know the limits!

Answer (score 4):

There are literally millions of biomolecules.  Some of them we know the structures and chemical properties of others we know nothing about.   I'm going to focus on sugars.  It would be too broad a question probably even to list all biomolecules, much less describe how their chemical synthesis would be performed.

The good news is that industrial manufacturing of biomolecules is done for thousands of compounds and even available.  Certainly chemical synthesis of sugars is possible and even available but is very expensive and often produces side products compared to fermentation processes or extraction from plants say.

Sugars, for instance [glucose](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Alpha-D-Glucopyranose.svg/200px-Alpha-D-Glucopyranose.svg.png) are very similar, but if you look at this structure you will see that the four OH (alcohol) groups could point up or down.  Any manufacture of glucose would have to get each one of these bonds exactly right.  This is D-glucose, which is commonly available as extracted with water from sugar beets and sugar cane.  I can buy 10 pounds of it at the store for less than $10.

[image: glucose]

Compare with L-glucose, which is synthesized by a chemist.  Its available (though not really recommended for human consumption because its got impurities and doesn't necessarily pass FDA definitions of purity to be a food) at the cost of [$87 per gram](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/g5500?lang=en&region=US).

So the answer is probably best put like this: who would pay \$87,000 for a bag of sugar when they could pay $10?  Cases where one would have to pay a company to produce a biomolecule, its going to cost...

Comment: Great answer, but my impression was that the question was about some sort of nanosynthesis.

Comment: why not write it up Alan?  there seem to be more than one way to read the question...

Comment: I don't have an answer to my reading of the question.

Comment: @AlanBoyd reword and make a new post

Comment: Thanks friends for your inputs. As Alan Boyd has mentioned, my question has to do with the methods available to manufacture. I am aware that synthesis is cheaper, but I want to know, if there is a system/machine which takes various aspects of the design of complex molecules (the knowledge gained through structural an functional studies) as input and gives the desired molecule as output. The machine has nano scale control to fix things at the right place and uses elements as the manufacturing material. Also, please give references to such work.

Comment: nano scale is not enough of a description in itself to answer this question, i still interpret the nano scale manipulation would still be a small scale of synthetic, enzymatic or fermentation methods.  we have no demonstrated way of making most biomolecules... there are practically an infinite number of them.  do you have a reference?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, molecules aren't synthesised that way. This is because the common atoms that in biomolecules (C, O, H, N, P) don't occur as individual atoms in nature and it would be extremely difficult (and unnecessary) to keep them in a single-atom state ready for assembly into a molecule in some way.

However, chemists *are* able to synthesise almost any kind of biomolecule desired by performing different routine reactions in a targeted fashion. The efficiency of production and the purity of the product obtained can vary extremely, but in principle any biomolecule up to a reasonable size could be synthesised chemically that way - as long as the desired product is itself chemically stable.

While theoretically, the repertoire of reactions you can do that way might be limited, there is no machine that does them routinely according to a program you put in, because there are too many variables that need to be adjusted depending on the current aim of synthesis and much more flexibility is needed than such a machine could provide.

I'm waiting for a reply from my chemistry friend on a few examples of those reactions.